# SSRS report parameters on enterprise portal resizing themselves

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report running accessible through Enterprise Portal in 2012 cu7. The report parameter web part displays fine when first loading the page, but when you interact with any of the parameters, it resizes itself very small, hiding the full parameter values.

The parameters are strings and dates. I have tried editing the web part to change its size and set it to fixed, though this only affects the frame of the web part and not the parameter box. Does anyone know what causes this or how to stop it and keep the parameters fully visible?

Thanks for helping, here are some screens for reference:

Before modifying params:

[image: Parameters web part before modifying parameters]

After:

[image]